# Lift - JE.Call() question

Tags: scala, lift

Could someone explain why this isn't working for me?  I am just trying to run a javascript function on a page that is already defined.  This is a basic alert command.

```
//On html page

<script type="text/javascript">
    function test(){
        alert('hi');
    }
</script>

//on lifty page
JE.Call("test")
```

I've stripped out a lot of the html/lift/scala code for the sake of the question.  For some reason, this will not call the js function in the html page, either on of the page or when say, an ajaxButton function is called.  I'm just trying to interact with the javascript on the html page.  I must be missing a key detail?

Thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

First, how are you returning the `Call`? Do you have an AJAX or Comet snippet on the page that will return that?

Second, are you sure that your `test` function is in the global scope such that the `Call` can, well, call it?

Related, what does your browser's Javascript console say? Are there any Javascript errors? That might indicate that test is not defined in the right scope. Do you see any network activity? If no then then the server-side part that would return the `Call` is not getting activated.

PS I was the last person to touch `Call`'s ScalaDocs and can update them again if you think they aren't sufficient.

Comment: Ah I found the problem, I was running the commands, above a JsCmds.SetHtml command, but I wasn't chaining it.  Doh  :P

Comment: One more question....say I want to chain some SetHtml commands together...and I want a message to display like "Updating", then do my process then change that display message to say "Completed"  When I chain, it just seems to go, but doesn't do a cascading update...is this by design in Lift?  Is there a way to force say a "flush" of the commands as they're executing?  Like this...  JE.Call("setMessage", "updating...") & JsCmds.SetHtml("myDiv", serverCallFunction) & JE.Call("setMessage", "completed task!")

Comment: The code you give will become, if I remember right and if you're using jQuery, `setMessage("updating..."); try{jQuery("#myDiv").each(function(i) {this.innerHTML = [result of serverCallFunction];});} catch (e) {}; setMessage("completed task!");`

Comment: I researched it, and the best way for me to accomplish my event queuing will be with actors.  :)